# toggle CSS class on click using jQuery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I try to do the following:

When I click on a specific DIV a CSS class is added/removed from another DIV.

Take a look here for a live example (and click on "click me"):
http://jsfiddle.net/fyehLqsc/

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mejs-play").click(function () {
      $(".spin-l").toggleClass("animated");
      $(".spin-r").toggleClass("animated"); 
    });
   });
```

It is working as it should, but when I do the same thing on my WordPress site, it's not working.

Take a look here:
*link removed*

What I want to achieve: If someone clicks on the play button which has the class "mejs-play" the class "animated" shall be added to "spin-l" and "spin-r".

Can anyone please tell me why it's working on JSFiddle but not on my site?

Comment: you hv a script error on document.ready function on ur wordpress site

Comment: So basically it is not even executing the toggleClass function because it control is never entering that point

Comment: What do I have to do to fix that? Sorry I'm a total noob on these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is running in noconflict-mode in wordpress, you can't access it via `$`

Use this:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".mejs-play").click(function () {
      $(".spin-l").toggleClass("animated");
      $(".spin-r").toggleClass("animated"); 
    });
   });
```

---

Edit:

as it seems the Medialelement-library stops the propagation of the click-event.

This works for me:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(   function ($) { 
    $('audio').on('play pause',function(e){  
      $(this).closest('.current-cast').prevAll('.cassette').last()
      .find(".spin-l,.spin-r").toggleClass("animated",e.type==='play');
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for that, now I don't get the error anymore but it's still not spinning when clicking the button. I edited it on my WP site.

Comment: You're my hero. Thank you so much for your help! Have a great Christmas time. :)

Comment: Frohe Weihnachten und guten Rutsch!